getting blocknote compile error in sublime text 3 but not webpack
When I run build in sublime text 3, with nothing more than the following references to Blocknote...
import "@blocknote/core/fonts/inter.css";
import { useCreateBlockNote } from "@blocknote/react";
import { BlockNoteView } from "@blocknote/mantine";
import "@blocknote/mantine/style.css";

...I get the following error
../../../../node_modules/@blocknote/core/types/src/editor/BlockNoteTipTapEditor.d.ts(13,22): error TS2415: Class 'BlockNoteTipTapEditor' incorrectly extends base class 'Editor'.
  Property 'createView' is private in type 'Editor' but not in type 'BlockNoteTipTapEditor'.

However, compiling with webpack (dev) completes without error.
Any advice?
using
    "@blocknote/core": "^0.14.2",
    "@blocknote/mantine": "^0.14.2",
    "@blocknote/react": "^0.14.2",

and sublime text 3 build 4169

What terminal command and current working directory do you have set up in your sublime-build file? If you go to that working directory in a terminal and run that command, does it do what you would expect?

I can't find any sublime-build files anywhere

Under Tools/Developer/View Package File, I selected Typescript.sublime build, which reads {
"target": "typescript_build",
"selector": "source.ts, source.tsx"
} but that doesn't really give me a clue as to where to find the builder

Looks like sublime is using typescript 5.4.5, whereas webpack ts-loader is using typescript 5.2.2. So I presume sublime is catching the error correctly. Meaning webpack will catch this error eventually, which means I can't use BlockNote until this is fixed.

Build systems that ship with packages are best viewed via View Package File from the command line. When they contain shell_cmd or cmd, they are executing external programs. When they have target (such as the TypeScript one), then the package that provides them has a special command that drives the build. So the place to look for how to configure it or to report issues would be with the maintainers of that package/the package documentation.

I've just been notified that the BlockNote developers have fixed this issue. Not yet released, but coming. :-)
